# There was an error with the file in gathercontent module of Drupal

Tags: importing-exporting

I am importing content from gathercontent platform using the [GatherContent](https://www.drupal.org/project/gathercontent) module.

All the fields get populated except media type which gives a warning that states :

```
"There was an error with the file"
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Gathercontent module retrive files(Media) using CURL. So check curl is enable on server.

Answer (score 0):

It might well be that your problem is caused by what is described in [issue 1908144](https://www.drupal.org/node/1908144).

That issue also mentions CURL (as in the comment to your question).

Curious to hear if this somehow helps ...

Comment: Just curious if you have had a chance to consider this answer ... and what your feedback might be